# L2TP/IPSec PreShared Key VPN

Tags: vpn, ipsec, l2tp

I tried to setup a L2TP/IPsec VPN server with PSK authentication according to [this](http://rootmanager.com/ubuntu-ipsec-l2tp-windows-domain-auth/setting-up-openswan-xl2tpd-with-native-windows-clients.html) tutorial on a Ubuntu server but there is a problem when I'm trying to connect to this server with a Windows 7 client. I can't connect using PSK however it works when I use certificate for authentication. I don't know why? Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 has some different settings from Windows XP which can affect compatibility; the most notable ones are the removed support for the MS-CHAP V1 authentication protocol (only MSCHAP V2 is supported) and different encryption settings for L2TP/IPSEC (as documented [here](http://www.fuzeqna.com/sonicwallkb/consumer/kbdetail.asp?kbid=8493)).

I don't know how this applies to Ubuntu, but maybe it can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. But MS-CHAP is completely disabled in my Windows 7 VPN client configuration and it's using CHAP protocol.

Comment: ...why?!? CHAP is *way* more insecure...

Comment: I think security is guaranteed by IPSec and L2TP key phrase. isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem due to my IPSEC/L2TP server (Ubuntu 12.04 precise) and clients (Windows 7 and Windows XP) being behind NAT. This required a [registry modification](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926179/en-us). After rebooting I was able to connect.